# How to alter content generated by Veiws module?

Tags: drupal

So i made a view in Views.Nothing to complicated,the views generates a page,and a content type [let's call it Animals] and all it's occurances (which are publihsed) are show ,sorted and filltered [no special settings...most basic view] ,now,i have in the 'Filter Criteria' a filter that filters the content type via the field_tags [which are used to describe the diff.entries in the content type Animals ,i.e. ... bird/fish/reptile/etc ] ( again,most basic use of taxonomy) which are exposed to the viewer of the webiste and he/she can click on any of the filter options to filter the results from the View.

The problem is the Views generates this exposed filter criteria as a '**select form**' with options. 
I do not want this...i wish to have a UL (unordered list).The rest of the generated content is just fine.

So how do i alter the generation of this Select feild into a UL ?

**I did it just fine via javascript ,but i do not wish to use .js for this,i'd rather do it via php...via some hook_function.**

If you need any more info ,feel free to ask :)

Ty for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) will give you a few more options on how to output the element.

For more control use hook_form_alter on the exposed filter form, look at drupal form api for more information on your options here.

Comment: Thank you very much...the BEF is really good and i will use it in future projects :)
But the hook_form_alter was the thing i was looking for ... :) thumbs up